# ValueError: '2' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%d%20%H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, datetimeoffset

I am trying to get data from an API that sends the time like "2022-08-15%2013:00:00" in string format, How do I convert it into a datetime format? I have tried -

```
start_time = "2022-08-15%2013:00:00"
start_dt_obj = datetime.strptime( str(start_time), r'%Y-%m-%d%20%H:%M:%S')
```

But this gives an error -

`ValueError: '2' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%d%20%H:%M:%S'`

How do I resolve this?

Comment: use `'%Y-%m-%d%%20%H:%M:%S'`

Comment: Use double percentage signs in the formatting string to denote a single literal percentage sign.

Comment: The double percentage sign worked Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`%20` is an URL encoded space character, so `2022-08-15%2013:00:00` should be in fact interpreted as `2022-08-15 13:00:00`. You can achieve that using `urllib.parse.unquote`

```
import datetime
from urllib.parse import unquote

start_time = "2022-08-15%2013:00:00"

start_dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(unquote(start_time), r'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(start_dt_obj)
```